# Get annotations of bean in BeanPostProcessor implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

I'm trying to implement my own BeanPostProcessor implementation.

```
@Component
public class UserDetailsProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof User) {
            User user = (User) bean;
            List<Annotation> beanAnnotations = Arrays.asList(user.getClass().getAnnotations());
            for (Annotation annotation : beanAnnotations) {
                UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) annotation;
                System.out.println(userDetails.firstName());
                System.out.println(userDetails.lastName());
            }
        }

        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

And this is my bean definition:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloReactiveApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloReactiveApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    @UserDetails(firstName = "Szymon", lastName = "Nowak")
    public User user() {
        return new User();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get annotations of bean, and proceed them somehow. I can clearly see why `user.getClass().getAnnotations()` not working, because it tries to get annotation from User class, and not annotations from bean definition. How can i get list of annotations on bean definition?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with that annotation?

Comment: In this example i just want to print fields (`System.out.println(userDetails.firstName());` , System.out.println(userDetails.lastName());), but later i would like to set this values in bean.

Comment: Actually, I just want to learn how to implement custom annotations with `BeanPostProcessor`

Comment: Why don't you just set them directly in the bean method? Why use the annotation?

Comment: As i said, I want to learn how to use `BeanPostProcessor`

Comment: `BeanPostProcessor` post processes beans, not bean method, not bean definitions. You might be able to inject the `ApplicationContext` into your BPP, retrieve the corresponding bean definition and go from there.

Comment: How can I retrieve corresponding bean definition from `ApplicationContext`?

Comment: Inject `GenericApplicationContext` instead. Or use what Artem suggests in their answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do something like:

```
BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) beanFactory;
BeanDefinition beanDefinition = registry.getBeanDefinition(beanName);
if (beanDefinition instanceof AnnotatedBeanDefinition) {
    if (beanDefinition.getSource() instanceof MethodMetadata) {
        MethodMetadata beanMethod = (MethodMetadata) beanDefinition.getSource();
        String annotationType = UserDetails.class.getName();
        if (beanMethod.isAnnotated(annotationType)) {
    ...
```

In other words even if it is `@Bean` method definition we can get all the info via its `BeanDefinition`.

Comment: Thank you. That's what i wanted to get.

Comment: One more. Is it possible to get Annotation instance, so i could cast it to my custom annotation (`UserDetails`)? To make something like '     beanMethod.getAllAnnotationAttributes()' but as Annotation class instead of that Map

Comment: `AnnotatedElementUtils.getMergedAnnotation()` ?

Comment: And how can i get AnnotatedElement - first argument of `AnnotatedElementUtils.getMergedAnnotation()`?

Comment: `java.lang.reflect.Method` is an `AnnotatedElement`: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html